# Getting co_await with boost::process::async_system working

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, c++-coroutine, boost-process

Like the title says, I want to co_await for a process spawned with boost::process::async_system.

So I'm doing something like this:

[**Example on Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7d395aec0e036be9)

```cpp
  namespace bp = boost::process;
  bp::async_pipe ap(io_);

  // Create the child process object with our parameters and a redirected stdout
  co_await bp::async_system(io_,
                            boost::asio::use_awaitable,
                            bp::search_path(command),
                            bp::start_dir(cwd),
                            bp::args(args),
                            bp::std_out > ap);
```

But I'm getting a very unhelpful error-message.

My assumption now is, that async_system is not compatible with co_await. Is there another (maybe generic) way to integrate 3rd party async mechanisms in boost::asio::awaitable?

(I feel a bit lost in this whole boost::asio / c++ coro topic. Google is not very helpful and the boost doc a bit too minimalistic for me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd mold the code a bit for style: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/33667a7d106de0e7

### The Real Problem

Now with the above, there's is still an error inside `my_coro` when you try to uncomment the `async_system` call.

Instead of reading the message, I looked at the code, figured that it should have worked, and looked at the implementation:

```
template<typename ExitHandler, typename ...Args>
inline BOOST_ASIO_INITFN_RESULT_TYPE(ExitHandler, void (boost::system::error_code, int))
    async_system(boost::asio::io_context & ios, ExitHandler && exit_handler, Args && ...args)
{
    detail::async_system_handler<ExitHandler> async_h{ios, std::forward<ExitHandler>(exit_handler)};

    typedef typename ::boost::process::detail::has_error_handler<boost::fusion::tuple<Args...>>::type
            has_err_handling;

    static_assert(!has_err_handling::value, "async_system cannot have custom error handling");


    child(ios, std::forward<Args>(args)..., async_h ).detach();

    return async_h.get_result();
}
```

After looking at the implementation, I figured that

```
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:651:9: error: no type named 'completion_handler_type' in 'class boost::asio::async_result<boost::asio::use_awaitable_t<>, void(boost::system::error_code, int)>'
```

indicates that Boost Process has not been updated to support newer `async_result` protocol, which instead of `completion_handler_type` appears to use the `initiate` member function. This gives the async_result implementation more options, which are probably required for `use_awaitable_t` tokens.

I'd raise an issue at the library.

Note that current `develop` branch has code underway that does seem to correctly support use_awaitable (e.v. `boost/process/v2/popen.hpp`)

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration! OK, so I was somehow right with my assumption that it's not supported currently. Thats bad, I hoped the cpp coro and boost asio/process stack is more production ready. I'm working on a REST API that need to make some (1-5 min taking) IO tasks. Nevertheless co_await and asio are awesome. =)

Comment: FYI: I tried the develop branch. The Error has changed but it still does not work. Than I tried to switch to process::v2 but after digging through error again, I saw that v2 requires https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_open.2.html . So I'm limited to Kernel 4.14 and cannot use this. My last possibility is to create a threadpool and launch the pocesses synchronous in this pool and co_await on the tasks there.